# Formula/Query returns "wrong" result

Tags: php, mysql, math

I got help for a previous problem/question, and just realized that the script I was given returns the "wrong" number/value (yet does not trigger php/mysql errors).  Here's the values:

ingredient #1: **20.216 calories**

ingredient #2: **134.4564 calories**

The script *should* return: **154.67** but instead returns: **91.35**

The code:

```
<?php
//The Recipe selected
$recipe_id = $_POST['recipe_id'];

/*****************************************
 * Total CALORIES in this recipe
 *****************************************/

echo '<h4>Total calories in this recipe:</h4>';

$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT SUM(ingredient_calories), ingredient_amount
  FROM recipe_ingredients
  INNER JOIN ingredients USING (ingredient_id)
  WHERE recipe_id = $recipe_id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $recipe_calories = (
    $row['SUM(ingredient_calories)']
    * $row['ingredient_amount']);
}
echo number_format($recipe_calories, 2);

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

The **ingredients** table, stores the default values and serving size for each ingredient.

The **recipes** table, stores/sets the recipe_id, and other data unrelated to the query)

The **recipe_ingredients** table, maps the ingredient(s) within a recipe and stores the amount(s) used in the recipe.

I'm sure it's a problem with the query, but I too wet behind the ears to determine the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**UPDATE:** Here's the table data, as requested

```
ingredients
-----------
ingredient_id
ingredient_name
ingredient_calories

recipes
-------
recipe_id
recipe_name

recipe_ingredients
------------------
recipe_id (fk)
ingredient_id (fk)
ingredient_amount
```

Comment: You have identified neither what is wrong with the output, or what output you are expecting.

Comment: can you post an URL to your website?

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong about the result? Maybe some numbers that are in the corresponding rows you're selecting?

Comment: Little johnny tables, just waiting to get his hands on this.

Comment: @sberry that is why I asked for URL

Comment: Please do something with your code, because it is very vulnerable to SQL Injection, so it is very very easy to compromise. You are getting a variable from POST and putting it into an SQL query without proper sanitization. You can also check http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @webarto That really should be something that you just have to type like `{{mysql_ code}}` or something for.

Comment: Aren't you just confused because you're multiplying your amount of calories with the amount of ingedrients? What is the ammount of ingredients in this case?

Comment: @ColeJohnson there should be autoreply if mysql_* is detected :)

Comment: Lots of great insight here, and I've noted it :)  @Sgarz there are 2 ingredients in this recipe, as shown above.  I made the changes via the 2 answers here, and still get the same result :/

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @sberry - It's *Bobby Tabes*, by the way, not *Johnny Tables*. :-)

Comment: just updated the op with the table info, if that helps :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT!

Made the following adjustments:

```
$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT ingredient_calories, ingredient_amount
  FROM recipe_ingredients
  INNER JOIN ingredients USING (ingredient_id)
  WHERE recipe_id = $recipe_id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $recipe_calories += (
    $row['ingredient_calories']
    * $row['ingredient_amount']);
}
echo number_format($recipe_calories, 2);
```

Problem solved :)

Comment: it seems very similar to an answer posted earlier: `SELECT SUM(ingredient_calories * ingredient_amount)`

Comment: yea but that didn't work on it's own.  i had to use some of the changes from the other 2 answers, along with my own adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want this:

```
SELECT SUM(ingredient_calories), ingredient_amount
```

Having `SUM` on one column and not on another is probably where your error lies.  In fact, I just get an error when I try this query in mysql (5.0.51a).

```
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no
GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Do this instead:

```
SELECT SUM(ingredient_calories * ingredient_amount)
```

And grab just that single column from the single result row in your php:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$recipe_calories = $row[0]
```

Comment: Sorry guys, i thought it would be a simple error in my syntax that could be spotted without the values...but I just edited the post with that info.  Thanks again!

Comment: i see what you're saying, but i'm confused as to how you think i should update the script.  can you please post the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, since you haven't actually stated what the problem is, however, `$recipe_calories` is overwritten for each row in the result. Perhaps you meant:

```
$recipe_calories = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $recipe_calories += (
    $row['SUM(ingredient_calories)']
    * $row['ingredient_amount']);
}
```

Although you should just do it all in SQL - there is no need to do the calculation with PHP.